# Getting ERROR 1064 (42000) while SIMPLY declaring a variable in SQL

Tags: mysql, database

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @var as int
> set @var = 21
> WHILE (@var > 0)               ' at line 1

Code:

```
DECLARE @var as int
    SET @var = 20               
    WHILE (@var > 0 )                   -- Condition
    BEGIN                             -- Begin
        PRINT replicate('* ', @var)       -- Print
        SET @var = @var - 1               -- Set
    END
```

Comment: The code which you privide look like specific for MS SQL (aka SQL Server), not for MySQL. Check your DBMS carefully.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, `@var` is not the same variable as `var`.

The `@var` form is a user-defined session variable. You can't declare this type of variable. It is created implicitly if you set it to a value. You can use it outside of stored routines. It has no fixed data type.

The `var` form must be declared with the `DECLARE` statement. You can use it only in a stored routine. It is a local variable within the routine you declare it. It must be declared with a data type.

Procedure parameters are similar to declared variables, in that they are local to the procedure, they must have a data type, and they don't have a `@` symbol.

If you `set @var = 20`, that does NOT set the value of `var`, and vice versa. These are two different variables.

Comment: *It is created implicitly if you set it to a value.* The variable acts like it exists in any case. If you have not set the value then it acts as existing variable with the value of NULL. I.e. more correct phrase should be "It is created implicitly with the value of NULL when you access it the first time". Of course if the access is the value setting then the value after this accessing statement is equal to this value.

Comment: *It is a local variable within the routine you declare it.* Not within the routine but in the code block (BEGIN-END) where it is defined in, or the closest outer block. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d0c71cb663e9e2e45ec7a81a7b83087f